# Removing characters by index from Ruby String

Tags: ruby, string

Given a sequence of inclusive string indexes,

```
str_indices = [[1,2],[7,8]],
```

what's the best way to exclude these from a string?

For example, given the above indices marked for exclusion and the string `happydays`, I'd like `hpyda` to be returned.

Comment: 1.8.7...thanks for all the answers, I'm running some tests

Comment: Better to use Array of Ranges to be more native. `[(1..2), (7..8), (10..20)]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Ranges:

```
str_indices=[[1,2],[7,8]]
str="happydays"
str_indices.reverse.each{|a| str[Range.new(*a)]=''}
str
=> "hpyda"
```

If you don't want to modifty the original:

```
str_indices.reverse.inject(str){|s,a|(c=s.dup)[Range.new(*a)]='';c}
```

Comment: How did you know that he mean ranges? :) I thoght it just a strange multidimensional array.

Comment: "inclusive" said 'Range' to me.

Answer (score 2):

Guess this is the best way of doing it.

```
str_indices = str_indices.flatten.reverse
string = "happydays"
str_indices.each{|i| string[i]=""}
```

Comment: except when your indices are [[1,2],[6,8]].  This returns "hpydy" instead of "hpyd".

Comment: @AShelly: Yes, you are right. I didn't read the question well. To fix it, an additional step would be added when I flatten the array.

Answer (score 1):

For ruby 1.9,

```
string = 'happydays'
[-1, *str_indices.flatten(1), 0].each_slice(2).map{|i, j| string[i+1..j-1]}.join
```

For ruby 1.8, write `require 'enumerator'` before this.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[1,2],[7,8]].reverse.inject('happydays') { |m, (f,l)| m[f..l] = ''; m }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun :)

```
str_indices = [[1,2],[7,8]]
str = "happydays"
str_indices.flatten.reverse.inject(str.split("")){|a,i| a.delete_at i; a}.join
#=> hpyda
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a functional programming approach, you don't have to worry about the order of indexes

```
str = "happydays"
indexes_to_reject = [[1,7],[2,8]] # Not in "correct" order, but still works
all_indexes = indexes_to_reject.flatten(1)
str.each_char.reject.with_index{|char, index| all_indexes.include?(index)}.join
```

It also works with ranges:

```
str = "happydays"
ranges_to_reject = [1..2, 7..8]
str.chars.reject.with_index {|char, index| 
  ranges_to_reject.any?{|range| range.include?(index)}
}.join
```

Answer (score 0):

The following does not require the ranges identified by `str_indices` to be non-overlapping or ordered in any way.

```
str_indices = [[4,6], [1,2], [11,12], [9,11]]
str = "whatchamacallit"

keeper_indices = str.size.times.to_a -
                 str_indices.reduce([]) { |a,(from,to)| a | (from..to).to_a }
  # => [0, 3, 7, 8, 13, 14]

str.chars.values_at(*keeper_indices).join
  #=> "wtmait"
```